# `parse_date_time2` function in lubridate package

Tags: r, date, lubridate

The help page for `parse_date_time2()` states it is a fast C parser of numeric orders. What is meant by "numeric orders" here?

Can someone give an example where this will not work because of not having a numeric order?

Answer (score 1):

The `parse_date_time2` function as a parameter named `orders=` which the help page describes as "a character vector of date-time formats". It's the ordering of the numbers representing year, day, month, etc in the string you are trying to parse. To be fast, `parse_date_time2` only recognizes a subset of orders as indicated by the `(!)` in the descriptions on the help page. The fast version does not recognize julian dates for example.

```
lubridate::parse_date_time("151-2001", "jY")
# [1] "2001-05-31 UTC"
lubridate::parse_date_time2("151-2001", "jY")
# Error in parse_dt(x, order, exact, FALSE, cutoff_2000) : 
#   Unrecognized format j supplied
```

It doesn't really matter if the ordering is numeric or not, it just matters if it's one of the formats that is in the faster parser used by `parse_date_time2`